# Is there a name/term for a static method that calls all instance methods of the same name?

Tags: javascript, oop

Given the following code, is there a name/term for a static method that calls an instance method of the same name for each existing instance?

Is this a common practice in any programming languages?

The use case is being able to make one function call and ensure all instances are affected without having to duplicate the code for the method.

**Note: this is just example code to illustrate the question**

```
window.MyClass = (function(){

    var _instances = [];

    function MyClass( name ){
        _instances.push( this );
        this.name = name;
    }

    MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function( arg ) {
        console.log( this );
        console.log( arg );
    };

    // This public static method calls the instance method of the same name for each instance
    MyClass.myMethod = function(){
        var i = _instances.length;
        while( i-- ){
            var instance = _instances[i];
            instance.myMethod.apply( instance, arguments );
        }
    };

    return MyClass;

})();

a = new MyClass('a');
b = new MyClass('b');

MyClass.myMethod( true );

console.log('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------');

a.myMethod(false);
b.myMethod(false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bryandowning/7sr87/

Comment: Having trouble understanding what you mean, are you talking about constructors?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about design patterns and may be a better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I've done this before, but I'd abstract it even more, to the point it is just a generic `forEach` on the instances, and you pass the method as a function.

Comment: It seems odd to keep a collection of concrete objects inside of the object. This sort of behavior would usually be implemented as a specialized Collection class, with a method that would invoke other methods on each member.

Comment: @elclanrs - That's exactly what I'm implementing in my real code, but I don't know what to name it!

Comment: @PeteScott - Sounds interesting, but I don't see how that's a whole lot different from this implementation. Doesn't that just move the class's instance store into a separate instance? It would make the functionality reusable, but it would still have the potential memory issues described in T.J. Crowder's answer.

Comment: @BryanDowning That would just move the instance storage into a separate object, but I think that's important—as a developer I would surprised if I called a method (albeit static) on a class and the method was applied to every instance of that class that I'd created. Using a collection object makes it much more obvious that the behavior will apply to a collection, and gives you control over specifically which objects will be modified as a result of that call. GC issues would still apply as long as the collection was reachable, but that's nothing new to collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...is there a name/term for a static method that calls an instance method of the same name for each existing instance?

No, although it shares *some* similarity to pub/sub.

If you track every instance created in anything other than a weak map (and JavaScript doesn't have those — yet [see [draft ES6 spec](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts) section §23.3.1 as of this writing]), you're ensuring those instances are *reachable*, and so they can't be cleaned up by garbage collection. That's not ideal.

Whenever feasible, a much better approach would be to have all of the instances have a reference to a shared underlying singleton object that is updated by the "static" method. They'll all see the change through their shared reference, but they won't be kept in memory by unnecessary references to their instances. (Example below.)

If it's important that they take *action* when the "static" method is called, then the more common pattern would be for them to observe a shared item for changes, and to have that item raise a change event. (E.g., pub/sub.) In effect, that's the same thing as your `_instances` array (since the publisher has to know which subscribers to call), it's just a more common approach to it. So in *that* case (needing to take action), "pub/sub" or "event subscriber" or "sink/source" or similar might be a relevant term.

---

Example of the shared data object:

```
window.MyClass = (function(){

    var shared = {};

    function MyClass( name ){
        this.name = name;
    }

    MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(shared.arg);
    };

    // This public static method calls the instance method of the same name for each instance
    MyClass.myMethod = function(arg){
        shared.arg = arg;
        console.log("set shared.arg = " + shared.arg);
    };

    return MyClass;

})();

a = new MyClass('a');
b = new MyClass('b');

MyClass.myMethod( true );

console.log('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------');

a.myMethod(false);
b.myMethod(false);
```

Comment: I don't think is that bad to keep references to the instances if you implement a `delete` method.

Comment: Fair point, but in your example, calling the static method doesn't call the instance method for each instance. So I would still have to call the instance method for each instance manually. It seems like it would be pretty common  and useful to call one method and have all instances of a certain class get updated. Is there a different way I'm not thinking of?

Comment: @BryanDowning: The point is that the "class" (constructor function) shouldn't have any kind of enduring reference to instances. *Needing* to call a method on all instances is, itself, a design issue. The above suggests a way of avoiding it, by having the instances share a common item that is mutated by the "static" method.

Comment: @elclanrs: The sheer number of memory leaks that would result from the *inevitable* failure to call that `delete` method makes it an absolutely last-ditch option. I've never had to go there so far. JavaScript programmers are so steeped in automatic memory management that expecting them to implement C-like malloc and free patterns is just not reasonable. :-)

Comment: I do have a `delete` method in my actual implementation. Also, in my particular case, I know I'll only ever be dealing with a few instances of this particular class. However, at any given time, I do NOT know which instances exist.

Comment: Well, _I_ don't really know...my private `_instances` store does. ;) Otherwise I'd have to make the instances globally accessible, and manually call the method for each instance IF the instance exists. I guess I'll read up on pub/sub implementations, but it seems kind of silly (in my case) to have an added step of the instances subscribing to an event. Although I do see the value in implementing such a thing on a larger scale.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure either how to name this pattern, and while I agree with T.J. Crowder that keeping a reference to the instances is bad practice, I would say is not that bad if you have a way to delete them, but yes, you have to be aware of possible memory leaks. I'd abstract this pattern even further. You could create an sort of interface, let's call it `Instantiable` and generate a "class" that has this functionality, for example:

```
var Instantiable = function(ctor, proto) {
  var instances = []
  Object.keys(proto).forEach(function(k) {
    ctor.prototype[k] = proto[k]
  })
  ctor.prototype.new = function() {
    return instances.push(this)
  }
  ctor.prototype.delete = function() {
    return instances.splice(instances.indexOf(this), 1)
  }
  ctor.forEach = function(method) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1)
    instances.forEach(function(instance) {
      instance[method].apply(instance, args)
    })
  }
  return ctor
}

var Person = Instantiable(
  function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name
    this.age = age
    this.new()
  }, {
    say: function() {
      console.log(this.name, this.age)
    }
  }
)

var peter = new Person('peter', 22)
var jon = new Person('jon', 25)

Person.forEach('say')
//^ peter, 22
// jon, 25

peter.delete()

Person.forEach('say')
//^ jon, 25
```

Comment: I totally dig this, and I like the name `forEach`. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's called collector behavior. Like a garbage collector your trying to lay claim to some element of memory but unlike a collector your never guaranteed deletion.   It is leaky. The garbage collector and other destructors often so are implemented without memory leak fears.